# Apache Solr : Data import handler exception - SetGraphicsStateParameters name for 'gs' operator not found in resources: /R7

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

configured data import handler  to process bulk PDF documents. after process 21000 documents. Process going to idle and not  processing all the documents.

When i see the log observed below things.

Please let me know is there anyway that i can ignore this issue or any setting do i need to update.

```
 Error:

2020-04-23 18:39:55.749 INFO (qtp215219944-24) [ x:DMS] o.a.s.c.S.Request [DMS] webapp=/solr path=/dataimport params={indent=on&wt=json&command=status&_=1587664092295} status=0 QTime=0
2020-04-23 18:39:55.972 WARN (Thread-14) [ ] o.a.p.p.COSParser **The end of the stream is out of range, using workaround to read the stream, stream start position: 4748210, length: 2007324, expected end position: 6755534**
2020-04-23 18:39:55.976 WARN (Thread-14) [ ] o.a.p.p.COSParser Removed null object COSObject{50, 0} from pages dictionary
2020-04-23 18:39:55.976 WARN (Thread-14) [ ] o.a.p.p.COSParser Removed null object COSObject{60, 0} from pages dictionary
2020-04-23 18:39:55.997 ERROR (Thread-14) [ ] o.a.p.c.o.s.SetGraphicsStateParameters **name for 'gs' operator not found in resources: /R7**
```

**No Unicode mapping for 198 (1) in font DDJQSL+Wingdings**

Regards,

Ravi kumar

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the documents observed that someof the documents size is more than 500mb.
So solr getting out of memory exception and need to increase the heap memory.
After doing that issue got resolved.